# Need a way to bidirectionally sync between android (ver 9 pie) phone and windows 10 pc over the LAN

Tags: windows-10, android, sync, wifi-transfer

The title pretty much sums up what I am am trying to accomplish. The only requirements that I have are:

1.) Everything must be done over my LAN (wirelessly) no servers allowed.

2.) It has to be free if possible, but really cheap if not (This is a hobby project so not looking to spend more than $5 USD on it max)

Answer (score 0):

**Sweech:**

There's an Android app called [Sweech](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sweech) that allows you to access your Android device's storage over WiFi, via a web interface on another device on your network.

The app itself is free but you can upgrade to the premium version for $2, which unlocks various other features, including HTTPS and the ability to set a username and password to prevent unauthorized access.

I've been using the premium version for a couple of years now and it's brilliant.

Sweech doesn't actually handle *syncing* itself but provides you with remote write access to your Android device's storage over your LAN, which gets you more than half way there. You can copy files to or from your Android device, as well as delete them.

I tried with Robocopy but it can't use this type of address (i.e. `https://192.168.1.2:4443/images`) as a source or destination.

Maybe a `wget` script can handle the actual syncing aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using SMBSync2 for about a year to sync my music folder to my Pixel and have loved it. You can always root your droid and setup rsync if you want to get fancy, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fosshub.com/MyPhoneExplorer.html) by [FJ Soft](https://www.fjsoft.at/en/highlight.php)

You can connect to your phone through WIFI and bidirectionally sync your android files/folders with windows 10.

You can automate this by setting up Multi-sync on connect.

Its free and open source.